# is there any configuration for solr 5.3.1 that enable opennlp integration?

Tags: solr, opennlp

I saw there was a [article in the Apache wiki on OpenNLP for Solr](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP).

Is it valid for current solr version 5.3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's better to keep it outside.
Here is a small project I tried. 
https://github.com/john77eipe/DeepQA

Answer (score 2):

No, if you have a look at [LUCENE-2899](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2899), you'll see that the code discussed was never added to trunk. You'll have to download/patch/update the code yourself if you're going to have it native to Solr.

It's probably a better idea to do all the NLP stuff outside of Solr, then index the result in a form suited for the task you're trying to solve.